# VSCode: How to make Run Above run only the cell above and not all cells above?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

The `Run Cell | Run Above | Debug Cell` options when splitting scripts into cells in VSCode with `# %%` is a pretty handy functionality. But when working with larger cells, I often find myself scrolling to the top of the cell to hit `Run Cell` in order to trigger the cell in question. Clicking `Run Above` does not trigger *only* the cell above, but rather *all* cells above.

In the snippet below, option `A` will return `this is cell 2`, and option B will return `this is cell 1` ***and*** `this is cell 2`. Is there any way to change the menu settings so that *only* the cell directly is run and option B would *only* return `this is cell 2`?

```
#%%
print('this is cell 1')

#%%
print('this is cell 2')

#%%
```

**VSCode image 1:**

[image]

Or does the flexibility exist wihtin VSCode to add a custom menu element like `Run Cell Above Only`?:

**VSCode image 2:**

[image]